# Disk Utility can't find free space and Recovery Mode can't resize

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I had Linux installed on my Macbook in dual boot with MacOS.

Today, I uninstalled Linux, so I erased the partitions on which it was installed from Internet Recovery Mode. But, now, when I want to resize my Mac partition to its original size (250GB) ( now it is 200GB, Linux had 50GB in total) one of these 2 things will happen:

1. If I try to resize it from inside the OS, in Disk Utility, it won't find any free space. It will show that I have 200GB available (my current partition) which is not true.
2. In Recovery Mode, I am able to see the free space of 50GB but I can't add it to my current partition, nor can I format it as another partition. It would get stuck on "Preparing to partition disk".

[image]
disk0s2 is the Recovery partition. Don't ask me why it's name is FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF.

[image]

Please, tell me that the solution is not to re-install/format everything. Thanks!

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Did you boot to Recovery Mode (which shouldn't be possible) or to Internet Recovery Mode? Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0`! Your EFI partition is also missing!

Comment: @klanomath Sorry, Internet Recovery mode. I edited the post with the output.

Comment: could you help me with my issue ? seems similar: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341059/cant-access-to-partition-in-mac-after-deleting-linux-partition

Answer (score 1):

Your EFI is missing in the partition table - the content should be still there though - and the Recovery HD's partition has the wrong type.

To salvage this you just have to rewrite the GUID partition table:

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities > Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list` and with the disk identifier of the internal disk found there: `gpt -r show diskX`. Usually it's disk0 - below I assume it's disk0. Use the disk identifier you have found in your environment in the commands below!
- Unmount the internal disk:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- Remove all partitions:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 1 /dev/disk0 
  gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
  ```
- Re-add all partitions:

  ```
  gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 391759648 -i 3 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 391350008 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  ```
- Verify disk and main volume and repair it if necessary:

  ```
  diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk0
  diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s2
  ```
- Resize the main volume:

  ```
  diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 100% #or 250g
  ```
- Reboot to your main volume

Comment: Can you confirm that this procedure won't delete any data? Just edit the disk partition table?